# Add an arrow when hovering an image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need some help.

I have the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.imagens1').mouseover(function(){
        div_imagem = $(this); //Div que tem a imagem
        p = div_imagem.find('p').first();
        texto_p = p.text();

        $('#lista1').find('p').each(function(){

            $(this).css('color','white');
            $(this).css('font-size','20px');

            if ( ($(this).text()).toLowerCase() == (texto_p) ){

                texto_lista = $(this); //Texto (elemento p da lista) respetivo à imagem

                //Podes por exemplo meter o texto P a negrito assim:
                texto_lista.css('color','#575658');
                texto_lista.css('font-size','26px');

            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

that searches in an image a text like "salas" and then goes to a list I have on the side to change its CSS so it gets highlighted.

Now I need to find a way to make an arrow appear when said thing happens.

Someone can help.

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: can post your html??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Btw, it's a good practice to always use english names for variables and the like, no matter what your mother tongue is.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c5tysxb3/3/
Here's both the HTML area and the JS.
It will appear broken tho. :s

Comment: And conexo, I'm sorry for writting the variable names in PT but I picked it up from programming in C :S

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to 'create an arrow' using JQuery.  Basically you would create the following HTML:

```
 <span class='arrow' style="font-size:36px">&#8678;</span>
```

and append after the found result.  So

```
 $('div.imagens1').mouseover(function(){
     ...
     $('.arrow').remove();
     ...

 if ( ($(this).text()).toLowerCase() == (texto_p) ){
     texto_lista = $(this); //Texto (elemento p da lista) respetivo à imagem
     //Podes por exemplo meter o texto P a negrito assim:
     texto_lista.css('color','#575658');
     texto_lista.css('font-size','26px');

     var arrow = $('<span></span>').css('font-size','36px').addClass('arrow').html('&#8678;')
     texto_lista.append(arrow);

 }
 ...
```

should work.

You'll need to play around with how the arrow looks and where it will be added in the DOM.  It's difficult to tell without seeing the HTML.  The HTML entity of an arrow could easily be replaced with an image.

Comment: Somehow the string of code you made errases the word :S  

Here's the fiddle with the html/css/js https://jsfiddle.net/c5tysxb3/3/

Comment: Try [https://jsfiddle.net/c5tysxb3/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/c5tysxb3/5/).  Can you mark as the accepted answer if this solves it?  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo elements to accomplish that.
Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9ws7gsv2/
You can change the pseudo element `content` property to be whatever you want, even a font icon like the popular [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).